# Is there a more efficient way than a CNN for object recognition if only one object needs to be recognized?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-recognition

It appears that currently the industry standard for object recognition is a CNN. However, if a system only needs to identify one type of object (ie people), is there a less resource intensive way to recognize the given object (maybe SVM or similar techniques?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CNN are the best approach to the problem (Since you are learning the features that represent the object). You have to think if you want to approach the problem as a binary one (specific object/background) or as an instance one (be able to identify a specific object but at the same time be able of identifying different instances of the same object)

[image: Binary] [image: Diferent instances]

Answer (score 0):

If by people you are referring to any person who comes into the frame of camera then i would recommend you to have a look at camshift algorithm. It's similar to k-means in a way.It explained in the following link
[Here it shows the process of how it tracks object and background for it.](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/df8/tutorial_py_meanshift.html)

You can also check Haar-Cascade once.
[Tracking faces,eye,nose etc. You just need to feed it with examples of how a face looks like](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html)

Hpoe This Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the object you want to identify. Most of the cases CNN will give the best result, and you have plenty free resources for many types of objects, (i.e., **people**). For objects can not find the free resources, I don't think there exists a particular technique for them.